# Https in nginx/reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

So I am trying to move an express/nodejs app from http to https. It sits behind 2 nginx servers, first one resolves the name and redirects to the IP of the app, the second is a reverse proxy living on the same box as the app. I was just wondering at which point in the chain I need to handle the https traffic? I'm assuming (but dont actually know/cant find any examples) it would be on the first nginx which would be set up with certificate and key and all traffic reaching the 2nd nginx (reverse proxy) would now already be unencrypted and would act the same as it did before. This is on a large internal network where I wont have direct control over the first nginx, so want to be sure how's best to do this before proceeding.

Thanks for any help/tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the first Nginx should be the one handling SSL. This is where you'd configure it to listen for incoming SSL requests:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.angus.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.angus.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.angus.com.key;
    ...
}
```

I don't know if you already have a cert, but if you need one for free, I've used  Certbot ACME client from Let's Encrypt CA, https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/, which generated and configured some of SSL setup process. What's especially nice about using this certbot, is that you can pick "Nginx" among other software engines, like Apache, and the operating system you're using, and it will provide setup installs instructions, an app to configure  Nginx, and a means to renew your cert.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! i'll have a go at getting it all sorted, now that  i have a bit of direction! :) Also, its on an internal network so will use our own CA, but thanks for the link anyways!